# Dropdownlist dependiente no funciona asp.net mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, model-view-controller

No me funciona el llamado al segundo `dropdownlist` ya eh buscado tutoriales pero ninguno me funciona.

Este es mi **controlador**:

```
[HttpGet]
        public JsonResult traerespecialidad(int idCategoria)
        {
            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
             List<TBMSMAEEspecialidades> lista = db.TBMSMAEEspecialidades.Where(x => x.idCategoria == idCategoria).ToList();
            return Json(lista, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
     GET: TBMSMAETickets/Create

public ActionResult Create()
        {
            List<TBMSCATCategorias> ca = db.TBMSCATCategorias.ToList();
            ViewBag.idCategoria = new SelectList(ca, "idCategoria", "tipoCategoria");
            ViewBag.IdEstado = new SelectList(db.TBMSCATEstadosTickets, "IdEstado", "Descripcion");
            ViewBag.idPrioridad = new SelectList(db.TBMSMAEPrioridades, "idPrioridad", "nombrePrioridad");
            ViewBag.IdUsuarioTec = new SelectList(db.TBMSMAETecnicos, "IdUsuarioTec", "nombre");
            ViewBag.idUsuario = new SelectList(db.TBMSMAEUsuarios, "idUsuario", "nombre");
            return View();
        }

     POST: TBMSMAETickets/Create
     Para protegerse de ataques de publicación excesiva, habilite las propiedades específicas a las que desea enlazarse. Para obtener 
     más información vea https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.


[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "idTicket,idUsuario,IdUsuarioTec,idPrioridad,IdEstado,idCategoria,idEspecialidad,titulo,descripcion,fechaTicket,estadoTicket")] TBMSMAETickets tBMSMAETickets)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.TBMSMAETickets.Add(tBMSMAETickets);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.IdEstado = new SelectList(db.TBMSCATEstadosTickets, "IdEstado", "Descripcion", tBMSMAETickets.IdEstado);
        ViewBag.idPrioridad = new SelectList(db.TBMSMAEPrioridades, "idPrioridad", "nombrePrioridad", tBMSMAETickets.idPrioridad);
        ViewBag.IdUsuarioTec = new SelectList(db.TBMSMAETecnicos, "IdUsuarioTec", "nombre", tBMSMAETickets.IdUsuarioTec);
        ViewBag.idUsuario = new SelectList(db.TBMSMAEUsuarios, "idUsuario", "nombre", tBMSMAETickets.idUsuario);
        return View(tBMSMAETickets);
    }
```

Esta es mi **Vista** del controlador:

```
<div class="form-group">
         @Html.LabelFor(model=>model.idCategoria,"idCategoria",htmlAttributes:new{@class= "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.idCategoria, ViewBag.idCategoria as SelectList,"Seleccionar", new {htmlAttributes= new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.idCategoria, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.idEspecialidad, "idEspecialidad", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.idEspecialidad, new SelectList(" "),"--Seleccione--",new{ htmlAttributes= new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.idEspecialidad, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Este es mi **script** para los `dropdownlist` no me sirve lo he llamado de diferentes formas:

```
@section scripts{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#idCategoria").change(function () {
                $.get("/Administrador/traerespecialidad", { idCategoria: $("#idCategoria").val() }, function (data) {
                    $("#idEspecialidad").empty();
                    $.each(data, function (index, dato) {
                        $("#idEspecialidad").append("<option value='" + dato.idEspecialidad + "'>" + dato.tipoEspecialidad + "</option>");
                    });
                });

                })
            });
    </script>
}
```

Necesito que funcione porque lo voy a utilizar en varias vistas.

Gracias de antemano.